# Titanium - iOS App internalization

Tags: ios, localization, titanium, appcelerator

I would like to clarify some points concerning the "[iOS App internalization](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Internationalization-section-29004892_Internationalization-Objective)"

This is my situation *(the app.xml is for internalization the name of the app)*

[image]

1. If the language of the device is set to (for example) **German** , in this case the language set to the app is **English**
2. If i have only the **it** folder , and the language of the device is set to (for example) **German** , in this case the language set to the app is **Italian**

So everything is right . ( or not? )

Now , the important point is : **how to change the default language of the app** (the default language is set to **en** - **english**). I searched for a solution ( for now no one had a solution , i looked everywhere , but i haven't found a solution) , and i think i found the solution now.

Adding this key to the tiapp.xml

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
            <string>it_IT</string>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

In this way, **following the point 1** , now the language is set to **it - italian** and not to **en - english**

Comment: I played with this feature previously with en and sp.  If the language settings on the device is set to Italian it would know to go into the 'it' folder to get the resources for the app.  Is that what you are asking how to do?  It should automatically switch based on the device's setting.  You shouldn't have to set it.

Comment: No i'm not asking that. I know how the management of localization works. I asked how to change the default language, which is always english if not changed.

Comment: This example shows them just using the 2 character 'it' in that string.  Also, I remember having some issues with this and I would clean the project and rebuild.  https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/158673/how-to-set-default-language-when-language-i18nxx-does-not-exist-